# Phases in iron carbon diagram

Tags: solid-state-chemistry

The definition of phase : 
Uniform chemical and physical composition.

So Alpha iron (0.001% carbon) and alpha iron (0.002% carbon)  are two different phases??

Answer (score 2):

Let me opt for a paradoxical answer. They are not different phases, but you can't call them one phase either. **There is no "them".**

That is, you can't have a system in equilibrium which contains two different areas with the said compositions, either separated by a phase border or not. If you try, they will mix and form a single phase with averaged composition. It will be uniform all right.

Sure, you may have such compositions in *different* systems, and indeed many would call them "*the same phase*" then, based on the very close properties, similar structure, and the fact that they will mix if you let them. But this approach may quickly lead to nonsense. Say, water and acetone will mix in any ratio; are they one phase? Suppose yes. What about acetone and hexane? The same answer applies for the same reason. Now what about water and hexane? Er, well...

So let's not compare phases from different systems in terms of "sameness". Keep your apples and oranges apart.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivan .But sometimes when we have metastable states...that is suppose both state exist in solids..the rate at which they will form an averaged composition will be very slow. In such cases,  they might exist like same for longer times. So here, what should I say ? Single phase or two phase or the concept of phase definition doesn't hold true in such cases?...thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have equilibrium, then the concept of phase doesn't fully apply.